# Serving an Angular dockerized application with Traefik in docker swarm

Tags: angular, docker, docker-swarm, traefik

I am trying to serve a site developed in Angular. Angular app is dockerized in an nginx container. I have a rails backend and a postgres database along with it.

### docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3.8"
services:

# Traefik
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.3
    ports:
      - target: 80
        published: 80
        mode: host
    command:
      - --providers.docker
      - --providers.docker.swarmmode
      - --entrypoints.http.address=:80
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - proxy
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`192.168.100.200`)"
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.hostname == node1

  postgresql:
    image : xxxxxx/custom-postgres:latest
    volumes:
       pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - proxy
    ports: ["5432"]
    environment :
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - DATABASE_HOST=postgresql
    deploy :
      mode: replicated
      replicas 1

  frontend :
    image : xxxxx/frontend-nginx:latest
    volumes :
      - /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    networks :
      - proxy
    ports  :
      - 80
    depends_on :
      - core-api
    environment :
      - BACKEND_HOST=http://core-api:3000/
    deploy:
      mode : replicated
      replicas: 1
      labels: 
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.docker.network=proxy
        - traefik.http.routers.frontend.rule=Path(/)
        - traefik.http.routers.frontend.priority=5
        - traefik.http.services.frontend.loadbalancer.server.port=80

  core-api                  :
    image                   : xxxx/core-api:latest
    command                 :
                            - /bin/sh
                            - -c 
                            - |
                              rails db:create db:migrate
                              rake db:seed
                              rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid
                              rails s -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0
    networks                :
                            - proxy
    ports                   : 
                            - 3000
    depends_on              : 
                            - postgresql
    environment             :
                            - DATABASE_HOST=postgresql
    deploy                  :
      mode                  : replicated
      replicas              : 1

volumes :
  pgdata:

networks      :
  app-net     :
    driver    : overlay
    name      : proxy
    attachable: true
```

The redirect should happen to http://IP/en/public/landing. It do not happen because the javascript files are no where to be found it seems, and it fails to complete the redirect. The javascript files are giving me `404` when seen in the developer tools of the browser. If I use this without Traefik everything works as it should. I tried the 'redirect' middleware but, I am not sure how to use it in this situation.

can someone tell me how to do the redirections with Traefik for angular apps ?

[image: problem 404 with javascript files]

[image: details]

Comment: I have not used traefik , read the documentation breifly of the product. Do you think the labels for traefik are required ```  labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`192.168.100.200`)" ```  the traefik hooks into docker daemon - to read metadata of deployed services uisng the labels under deploy section ... try to play around - seems like a simple use case should work ...

Comment: @vbn I am new to it as well. Trying to get my head around the concepts. I think `raefik.http.routers.api.rule=` that is a mistake. `api` is the internal name for the Traefik api. Yes I will try change things once, I finish reading the Traefik documentation. It is important that I should get it working.